# I cant Parse the JSON but I can view the JSON from web

Tags: android, json

I cannot parse JSON.
My ParseJSon

[image]

GetJSOn

[image]

```
{"server_response":{"id":"1","email":"josephine_locsin@gmail.com","password":"7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b","first_name":"Josephine","last_name":"Locsin","title":"Chief Executive Officer, Tumandok Crafts Industries","skype_name":"echo123","filename":"1.jpg","birthdate":"1979-04-10","about_me":"Chief Executive Officer, Tumandok Crafts Industries And Former President, Association For Negros Producers (ANP)","facebook":null,"twitter":null,"google_plus":null,"linked_in":null,"address":"Bago City","gender":"Female","civil_status":"Married","user_type":"client","client_type_id":"1","province_id":"10","is_online":"2","is_activated":"1","last_activity":"2016-02-26 11:29:36","date_registered":null,"agencies":false}}
```

Comment: This is my JSON String to parse

Comment: what is your response which is coming from web

Comment: Always post your code in text format not as image.

Comment: Please post `parseJSON` method, actual JSON and error you are getting **in text format** not image.

Comment: Please elaborate question, what is main problem? and paste your json as well.

Comment: I'm not getting an error format. There were no values in my variables. it says "null"

Comment: Check `consultant_id`. Seems the main issue.

Comment: I just want to get the value and put it on my variable and. put it on textview. dats all

Comment: @FahadBinZafar i think its not the issue because i can see my JSON String printed in my textView. the problem is on parsing .. it doesnt assign value in my variable

Comment: @NeboyTrinidad ok. check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your server_response is not jsonArray, it is a `JsonObject`

Comment: Problem Solved thank you 
 jsonObject = new JSONObject(willParse);
//jsonArray = jsonObject("server_response");
      JSONObject JO = jsonObject.getJSONObject("server_response");

Answer (score 0):

In `doInBackground` why you are returning null `return = null`. Instead you have to return the response. so change it